# Which is the best way to get continues location updates from running background service with battery optimization?

Tags: android

I have to create an app which runs a service in background and continually update the current location on the server or we can say i have to send my current location at some points. The solutions i have think are following. please look at that and give me some idea.

1. Running an service in background with boot-starter.
2. Implementation of alarm manager so service can be started automatically if android kills it.
3. If my current location is in the radius of the 500 from my points than start to update on server.
4. and other logic which i have think to prevent continues server update.

I have research on it and found it consumes much battery of phone. So please suggest me how can i optimized it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways that can keep your Battery work for a long time though you are using GPS Application.

- Turn the GPS function off when not in use, then on when you need a
  location.

There are some more ways that you can keep track that GPS doesn't drain much Battery, just read this [`BLog`](http://www.backcountrynavigator.com/content/android-gps-apps-and-battery-life) to get some more idea about it.